# How to Insert Blob Datatype Values in Oracle 11g Database Through SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle11g, blob, sqlplus

I have created a table with Blob datatype but I do not know how to insert values into the table or view the table content using SQL*Plus. Please help me.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what kind of data you want put into a BLOB. Let's consider the table:

```
create table b1(id number , b blob);
```

If your data represented as hex-string you should use TO_BLOB function

```
insert into b1 values(1,to_blob('FF3311121212EE3a'));
```

SQLPLUS also shows BLOBs as hex-string

```
select * from b1;

----- -----------------------------------
   ID                                   B
----- -----------------------------------
    1 FF3311121212EE3A
```

Please refer Oracle documentation on [Using LOBs](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db111/search?word=using+lobs&partno=)

Comment: thanx Naeel for the reply. i am trying to store pdf file on my database. And i want to fetch the pdf file from the database to my jsp page. plz help me. its urgent!!!

Comment: Look at [this](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/LOBs/LOBS_10.shtml) If file is stored on a server in the folder described with **CREATE DIRECTORY** then it is possible to use DBMS_LOB package to read the file and put it into a table.
Regarding to JSP there are two ways, I think. 1) just extract to the folder accessable for the web-server, and give URL to the client. 2) load file and return it directly as http-response. See [examlpe](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=33374)