# How to insert 8796 character long data having data type as BLOB in table using sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I want to insert 8796 character long data having data type as BLOB in one table using sql quesry. but getting below error :

SP2-0027: Input is too long (> 2499 characters) - line ignored

Comment: Which dbms? (That's a product specific problem!)

Comment: Have you tried "insert into your_table values(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(Data));" ??

Comment: I tried with that also... but same error..

Comment: @jarlh                      it's sqlplus

Comment: Same question: [how to insert blob datatype values in oracle 11g database through sqlplus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380823/how-to-insert-blob-datatype-values-in-oracle-11g-database-through-sqlplus)

Comment: tried with to_blob also.. but still same error

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of sqlplus. Best advise is to use sql developer instead.

Comment: Well you could try cast the string to Long and save Long to Blob.

Comment: Treat your input as an array, loop through this array until you reach say 2400 chars/digits and update that part in the row where the Blob is, e.g. "update <your_table> set <blob_var> = <blob_var> || <string_var_from_array>.